# TypeError: Illegal invocation in the pubads_impl_XXX.js in Mobile Safari

Tags: javascript

I have a website with DoubleClick. In Sentry (error tracking) there are some errors in pubads_impl_xxx.js, but only in the Mobile Safari. Why is that? Should I ignore them or is there some way to fix them?

Thanks

```
TypeError: Illegal invocation
  at HTMLDocument.document.createEvent(:1:40918)
  at Wc.l(/gpt/pubads_impl_2020101501.js:6:89381)
  at $c(/gpt/pubads_impl_2020101501.js:6:15725)
  at bd.next(/gpt/pubads_impl_2020101501.js:6:16017)
  at ? (/gpt/pubads_impl_2020101501.js:6:29861)
  at new Promise(<anonymous>)
  at Xa(/gpt/pubads_impl_2020101501.js:6:29629)
  at Po.jn.dispatchEvent(/gpt/pubads_impl_2020101501.js:6:89295)
  at cz._.q.Yb(/gpt/pubads_impl_2020101501.js:6:262763)
  at Object.<anonymous>(/gpt/pubads_impl_2020101501.js:6:120833)
```

Comment: Pavel, I do not have Mobile Safari, but I know that createEvent is deprecated. Maybe Mobile Safari has already removed support to it. Can you try using an event constructor? See more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createEvent

Comment: Can you show us the function where the error is thrown?

Comment: @LajosArpad The script is from doubleclick by google - https://securepubads.g.doubleclick.net/gpt/pubads_impl_2020102201.js so I cannot change it. I'm just curious why this happens and how to avoid it (or if I should ignore it :D)

Comment: It's depraceted, but by webkit documantion it should work https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkitjs/document/1631381-createevent?language=javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a known [ISSUE 1811](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-javascript/issues/1811) sentry-javascript and is related to `blacklistUrls` not working on iOS9 Mobile Safari.

Suggested solution is to either update `blacklistUrls` to use a regex or handle check in `beforeSend` callback.

In the code attached in the issue, error was happening due to facebook crawlers, you can do similar check find out what url Google crawlers are using.

```
Sentry.init({
  beforeSend: function (event) {
    // Drop all events if query string includes `fbclid` string
    if (location.search.indexOf('fbclid') !== -1) return null;
    // Otherwise just let it though
    return event;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, since it only occurs on the Mobile Safari I've also added UA check for iOs.

Comment: But fbclid is also present if it's a real user that came from Facebook, am I wrong?